# Keyword 'with' not working in MySQL 8 Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
with
    converted as (select convert(v using utf8mb4)
                         collate utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci as v from t),
    offending as (select v from converted group by v having count(*) > 1),
    duplicates as (select converted.v from converted join offending
                               where converted.v = offending.v)
select * from duplicates as a join duplicates as b
          where a.v = b.v and
          a.v collate utf8mb4_bin > b.v collate utf8mb4_bin;
```

When I paste this in Workbench, it's saying the following:

**"with is not valid at this position for this server version"**

I am using the latest versions of MySQL 8.0.19 and Workbench 8.0.19.

When I use this query, this work just fine:

```
with
    converted as (select convert(band_or_artist using utf8mb4) 
                         collate utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci as v from music_band_or_artist), 
    offending as (select v from converted group by v having count(*) > 1)
select count(*) from offending;
```

Can anyone help me rewrite this first query to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that once you consume your `converted` CTE in the `offending` definition, you can't use it again.  One workaround would be to define `converting` twice:

```
WITH converted1 AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(v using utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci AS v FROM t
),
converted2 AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(v using utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci AS v FROM t
),
offending AS (
    SELECT v FROM converted1 GROUP BY v HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
),
duplicates AS (
    SELECT c.v FROM converted2 c
    INNER JOIN offending o ON c.v = o.v
)
SELECT *
FROM duplicates a
INNER JOIN duplicates b
    ON a.v = b.v AND
       a.v COLLATE utf8mb4_bin > b.v COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be on the right track, I'm just getting `Column 'v' in field list is ambiguous` now because it's being used in both `converted1` and `converted2`.

Comment: Select `c.v` inside the `duplicates` CTE...I think this was the problem.